# CodeIgniter 3 redirect function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I'm in the process of re-coding and updating my CMS I've got working in CI2, to CI3, and for the life of me I cannot get my redirect function to work for me on CI3.

Outside of redesigning my Models, my code thus far is is identical to my CI2 code. Originally I suspected my layout hook was the culprit, but I've completely disabled him and I'm still not getting anywhere.

```
public function login ()
{
    //var_dump(logged_in());
    //if (logged_in())
        redirect('/user/');
}
```

Above is the entirety of my login function at the moment, from my User controller. I've removed all the other code in an effort to pinpoint this problem. I've even commented out the `if` statement thinking that it might even by the culprit. nope.

My `logged_in()` function returns TRUE, or FALSE, depending on certain things set in my user sessions. That appears to be functioning fine. As far as I can tell, my configs settings looks good. I have the URI helper autoloaded, and other URI helper methods function properly.

Now for the strange part. When I visit /user/login, not only does my page not redirect, if I un-comment the `var_dump()` before the redirect (which returns true), and re-comment it, the page doesn't update, and I have `bool(true)` on my screen regardless. If the `var_dump` is commented and I open a new tab to `users/login` it simply doesn't load anything, and it just hangs out as a new tab.

**Edit**: I've forgotten to mention that when I use the 'refresh' flag (`redirect('/user/', 'refresh');`), that simply takes me to an about:blank page.

**Edit#2**: I've copied the CI3 files into a new "project", and even those wont redirect using the built in Welcome_Message view/controller combo.

Comment: have you followed the naming conventions in `CI3`??

Comment: All my other code functions (so far...) correctly, I fail to see how the redirect can be so nonfunctional based on a naming conventions. 

However, my `login` function is part of `class User extends Front_Controller`, and `Front_Controller` extends `MY_Controller`.

Comment: `MY_Controller` is in core??

Comment: My redirects are now taking me to the index() of which ever Controller they're called in. Not helpful either.

Comment: Correct, its in Core. The `MY_Controller` file contains `MY_Controller`, `Front_Controller`, and `Admin_Controller`.

Comment: First off you may need to configure some routes. Second make sure url helper is auto loaded. `redirect('user');`  On codeigniter 3 make sure the class and file name start with first letter upper case example `class User extends CI_Controller` and file name: User.php

Comment: `url` is being auto-loaded.

`class User extends Front_Controller` is found in `User.php`.

Comment: Interesting development, if I go to... say, `/user/asdf`, and then `/user/login`, my redirect is dropping me back onto `/user/asdf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through a lot of trial and error, I've since discovered my problem. When I performed `var_dump(base_url)` I found out that I was `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`, and since I was working locally, that is ::1. What I learned was base_url wasnt working like it was in CI2. Sadpanda.

`Base_url` config variable was incorrectly set. In `config/config.php` my `base_url` was set using a single quote. Allowing CI3 to guess the protocol, it would default to `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`, which would return `::1` since I am working locally. Furthermore, when I set the variable to `'http://localhost/supersecretname'`, using single quotes the exact same problem popped up as when it was using the auto `SERVER_ADDR`

By some miracle of sleep deprivation, I was trying many different values here, and at some point I switched from single, to double quotes.

And thus, a solution was found.

`$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/supersecretname";`

Comment: adding double quotes on the redirect param url worked for me as well.

Answer (score 7):

Add ob_start(); to Controller

```
<?php
ob_start();
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cart extends CI_Controller {
 // code here

}
```

Comment: thanks for this and for those wondering: This is commonly used to so that pages can send headers 'after' they've 'sent' some content already (ie, deciding to redirect half way through rendering a page)

Answer (score 0):

Add `base_url()` in redirect function.

```
 redirect(base_url().'user', 'refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

`redirect('Admin/index')` was not working until I removed `echo` statement and `print_r` from the function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).